# AWS Lambda can't query RDS because don't have cluster arn

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, rust, aws-lambda, amazon-rds

I am trying to query a Postgres DB hosted in AWS RDS from Lambda. I am passing it the DB ARN. I do not have a cluster; don't want one. It is saying "invalid cluster arn" when I pass it the DB ARN. I don't not want to pay more for a cluster.

This is my query:

```rust
let db_arn = "arn:aws:rds:us-east-1:12345678910:db:mydbname";
let st = rds_client
        .execute_statement()
        .resource_arn(db_arn)
        .database("postgres")
        .sql(get_symbols_query)
        .secret_arn(secret_arn);
```

The exact error is: `Invalid cluster arn: arn:aws:rds:us-east-1...`

How do I solve this?

Comment: Are you using an [`aws_sdk_rdsdata::client::Client`](https://docs.rs/aws-sdk-rdsdata/0.24.0/aws_sdk_rdsdata/client/struct.Client.html#method.execute_statement)? If so, please note that the **AWS RDS DataService** is only available to run SQL statements on an Amazon Aurora Serverless v1 DB cluster. Is your Amazon RDS PostgreSQL database running on Amazon Aurora Serverless? If not, then you will likely need to connect to the databased using a JDBC client.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein what is the simplest way to connect to a private MySQL (non-Aurora) RDS instance from a Lambda in Python? Just connect to RDS from Lambda like in [GCP](https://cloud.google.com/blog/topics/developers-practitioners/how-connect-cloud-sql-using-python-easy-way).

Comment: @rkochar Please create a new Question rather than asking via a comment on an old question.